# Evaluate a double integral.

Tags: calculus

> To find:

$$I =\int\int_Rx(1+y^2)^{\frac{-1}{2}}dA$$

> R is the region in the first quadrant enclosed by $y=x^2$, $y=4$, and $x=0$

$$y=x^2, y=4,x=0, (x= y^\frac{1}{2})$$

$$R=((x,y), 0 \le y \le 4, x^2 \le y \le 4)$$

> i.e.

$$R=((x,y), 0 \le x \le 2, x^2 \le y \le 4)$$

$$I=\int_0^2\int_{x^2}^4x(1+y^2)^{\frac{-1}{2}}\,dy\,dx$$

> Where to from here?

Comment: Try setting it up in $dx\,dy$ order. Then will be easier to integrate the $dy$.

Comment: You can use `\iint` to get a double integral with proper spacing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done very simply like this
\begin{align}
I=\int_{0}^{4}\!\int_{0}^{\sqrt {y}}\!{\frac {x}{\sqrt {{y}^{2}+1}}}
\,{\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y
\end{align}
\begin{align}
=\int_{0}^{4}\!{\frac {\int_{0}^{\sqrt {y}}\!x\,{\rm d}x}{\sqrt {{y}^{2
}+1}}}\,{\rm d}y
\end{align}
\begin{align}
=\int_{0}^{4}\!1/2\,{\frac {y}{\sqrt {{y}^{2}+1}}}\,{\rm d}y
\end{align}  using $[y^2+1 = u^2]$
\begin{align}
=1/2\,\int_{1}^{\sqrt {17}}\!1\,{\rm d}u
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\approx 1.561552813
\end{align}

Comment: You can use double dollar signs instead of single dollar signs to get displayed equations, and sections contained in `\begin{align}` and `\end{align}` to align the equality signs in consecutive equations.

Comment: The last equal sign should be an approximation sign.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{eqnarray*}
% \nonumber to remove numbering (before each equation)
   I&=&  \int_0^4\left(\int_0^{\sqrt{y}}\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}dx\right)dy\\
   &=& \int_0^4\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}\left(\int_0^{\sqrt{y}}xdx\right)dy \\
   &=& \frac{1}{2} \int_0^4\frac{y}{\sqrt{1+y^2}} dy\\
   &=&\frac{1}{2}\left[\sqrt{1+y^2}\right]^4_0\\
   &=&\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{17}-1\right)
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Why is $\sqrt{1+y^2}$ at $y=4$ equal to $3$?

Comment: You can use `\left` and `\right` to let parentheses and brackets adapt to the size of their content.

Comment: Your result is wrong.

Comment: @user202729 Sorry, I've corrected the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

As you defined well,
$$
R=\left\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: 0\leq x \leq 2, x^2 \leq y \leq 4 \right\}.
$$
So
$$
I =
\int_{R} \frac{x}{\sqrt{1+y^2}} \mathrm{d}A =
\int_0^2 \left( \int_{x^2}^4 \frac{x}{\sqrt{1+y^2}} \mathrm{d}y \right) \mathrm{d}x
$$
Here, either you do a change of variables or you check in any table that:
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}\sinh^{-1}(z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}
$$
So
\begin{align}
I &= \int_0^2 \left[ x\sinh^{-1}(y) \right] ^{y=4}_{y=x^2} \mathrm{d}x \\ 
 &= \int_0^2 \left( x\sinh^{-1}(4) -x\sinh^{-1}(x^2)\right) \mathrm{d}x = \\
&= \left[\frac{x^2}{2}\sinh^{-1}(4)\right]^{x=0}_{x=2} - \int_0^2x\sinh^{-1}(x^2) \mathrm{d}x \\
&= 2\sinh^{-1}(4) - \frac{1}{2}\left[x^2 \sinh^{-1} \left(x^2\right) -\sqrt{x^4+1}\right]^{x=0}_{x=2}\\
&= 2\sinh^{-1}(4) - \frac{1}{2} \left(4 \sinh ^{-1}(4)+1-\sqrt{17}\right) \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{17}-1}{2}.
\end{align}